How to correctly understand the quote "I'll jump! And I will, too."?
In the famous Dumb-Hounded cartoon, the wolf threatens Droopy that if he comes one step closer: "I'll jump! And I will, too."
It's obviously meant to be comical, and it seems to be an unusual way to use of the expression "I will, too".
Is this just a way to say "I'll certainly do it"?

Yes. If it's a character speaking with high emotion, in a persuasion-argument mode. It's the essence of "And I'm not just saying that, I will actually do it."

Yes, in the context of the passage you quote, the sentence And I will, too could be paraphrased as I really will. So here, the speaker is not using and to add a further fact, but rather to augment their previous statement with a clarification of their sincerity in having uttered it.

I seem to remember that this question was asked before...[+1]
